# Failed to get followers count of 'b'metapodcode'' ~empty list

Tags: python-3.x, instapy

With the June 2022 update, there have been some changes in Instagram's APIs.  There was a [discussion](https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/blob/2a157d452611d37cf50ccb7d56ff1a06e9790ecb/instapy/util.py#L2642) here about changing or updating this code. You can find the discussion [here](https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6615) then i did some research on this topic and i found the fix [here](https://github.com/mifi/SimpleInstaBot/issues/125#issuecomment-1189878472) but this code is written in another javascript language, if the code here is integrated into instapy, it seems that all the problem will be solved. Instapy is an application that I love, but I've been looking for a solution to this problem for days and I'm not good at programming languages. I'm trying to get help here as a last resort. I'm waiting for your help

INFO [2022-07-22 03:20:06] [metapodcod]  Failed to get following count of 'b'metapodcod''  ~empty list
WARNING [2022-07-22 03:20:06] [metapodcod]  Unable to save account progress, skipping data update
b"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

```
INFO [2022-07-22 03:20:07] [metapodcod]  Sessional Live Report:
        |> No any statistics to show


[Session lasted 2.5 minutes]
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
INFO [2022-07-22 03:20:07] [metapodcod]  Session ended!
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\metapodcod\InstaPy\yeni.py", line 41, in <module>
    with smart_run(session):
  File "C:\Users\metapodcod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\metapodcod\InstaPy\instapy\util.py", line 1983, in smart_run
    session.login()
  File "C:\Users\metapodcod\InstaPy\instapy\instapy.py", line 475, in login
    self.followed_by = log_follower_num(self.browser, self.username, self.logfolder)
  File "C:\Users\metapodcod\InstaPy\instapy\print_log_writer.py", line 21, in log_follower_num
    followed_by = getUserData("graphql.user.edge_followed_by.count", browser)
  File "C:\Users\metapodcod\InstaPy\instapy\util.py", line 501, in getUserData
    get_key = shared_data.get("entry_data").get("ProfilePage")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: please provide code to reproduce your issue not just links. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hello my friend, i shared the code pieces related to the problem i had. What I said about how the solution will probably be in the article may be wrong. Someone with a good understanding of Python will appreciate this. There are very long codes in those links and if I add them here, it may fill the screen of the users who will look at this question :)

Comment: [here](https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6615#issuecomment-1171706411) replace the modified files